# How to prevent escape of a ~ (tilde) character in LaTeX document using R markdown and pandoc?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am preapring a scientific article manuscript using R Markdown. My R Markdown file is first converted to Markdown by knitr and then to LaTeX code by pandoc.

In LaTeX, the `~` character is used to indicate a non-breaking space. [It is considered good style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/when-should-i-use-non-breaking-space) by some journals to use the `~` character in front of `\ref` or `\cite`. For instance, LaTeX code like `Section~\ref{...}` and `Figure~\ref{...}` or rather `Sect.~\ref{...}` and `Fig.~\ref{...}` is expected by my journal.

Trying to use R Markdown to generate LaTeX code as close as possible to the journal's guidelines, I try to use `Sect.~\ref{...}`, but this is converted to `Sect.\textasciitilde{}\ref{...}` by pandoc.

How can I prevent pandoc escaping the `~` character to `\textasciitilde{}` to obtain the valid LaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found in the pandoc manual ([1](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.pdf), [2](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#)) that using `Sect.\ \ref{...}` solves the problem:

> A backslash-escaped space is parsed as a nonbreaking space. It will appear
>   in TeX output as `~` and in HTML and XML as `\&#160;` or `\&nbsp;`.

`Sect.\ \ref{...}` in the Markdown file is compiled to `Sect.~\ref{...}` in the LaTeX file as intended.